# SpringController Servlet.init() exception when sending mail

Tags: spring, jsp

I am trying to sending the mail.but it showing the HTTP status 500 - Servlet. init() for servlet Spring Controller threw exception. The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.the

I am sending the mail through default mail id but mail can't be send.

emailform contains the to and subject, message fields.default mail id given in to the spring-mvc.xml. so we cant find out the error please check once my code anything is wrong.i am given everything is correct .but its shows the Servlet.init() for servlet SpringController threw exception.

**Exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet SpringController threw exception     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
        org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
        org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

**SendEmailController.java**

```
package net.codejava.spring;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sendEmail")
public class SendEmailController {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doSendEmail(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // takes input from e-mail form
        String recipientAddress = request.getParameter("recipient");
        String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
        String message = request.getParameter("message");

        // prints debug info
        System.out.println("To: " + recipientAddress);
        System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);

        // creates a simple e-mail object
        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
        email.setTo(recipientAddress);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(message);

        // sends the e-mail
        mailSender.send(email);

        // forwards to the view named "Result"
        return "Result";
    }
}
```

**EmailForm.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Email with Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Sending e-mail with Spring MVC</h1>
        <form method="post" action="sendEmail">
            <table border="0" width="80%">
                <tr>
                    <td>To:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="recipient" size="65" /></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Subject:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject" size="65" /></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Message:</td>
                    <td><textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="message"></textarea></td>
                </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Send E-mail" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**spring-mvc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codejava.spring" />

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="srinivasaraojella@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="srinu877$@" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Error</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>EmailSpringMVC</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>EmailForm.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: can please tell clearly